# The results are not correct when predicting the future for a very long period of time with LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, python, long-short-term-memory

I am currently using LSTM to try to predict future data in AirPassengers.csv.

This is current code op my Colab (sorry for the comments are Japanese)
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16Ntg3dA5ywZvm35PEeMUjHtKhNdsSgbc?usp=sharing

I wanted to use this code to make predictions for a much longer period of time with different data in the future, so I changed the prediction period in the last code block from the original code I referenced from 3 years to 20 years as follows:

```
#from 
pred_time_length = 12*3
#to
pred_time_length = 12*20
```

When I do this, I get values like this damped oscillation, and I think that the prediction is probably not working well.

What is the cause of this? Also, what should I change in the code to make it work?

[image]

thank you in advance!